# Where to store a Servlet's singletons?

Tags: java, singleton, servlets

If my `Servlet` class uses a singleton (such as a manager class), where should it be stored?  The servlet itself, or in the `ServletContext`?

Can a servlet container create more than one instance of my `Servlet` class to handle requests?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is certain that there will be [only one instance of a Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042930/should-a-servlet-container-create-new-javax-servlet-http-httpservlet-instance-for/4043223#4043223). But still, it's better to store it in the `ServletContext`. Thus it will be accessible from other servlets as well.

Comment: Indeed and you can eventually use `ServletContextListener` to prepare/create the manager class and put in application scope (the `ServletContext`). See also for example [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468150/using-init-servlet). The manager class in question doesn't necessarily need to be a singleton as well. Just create one instance and put it in application scope once. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

You can store it basically anywhere you want; in a session, application context or as a field of that servlet itself. Just be sure to make it immutable since you're dealing with a multithreaded environment and your servlet will be called multiple times at once.

*Edit*: as Bozho pointed out, using a session might not be the best option, so you should evaluate your needs before putting your singleton in a session.